# laravel passport oauth2 live server unauthenticated 401

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I have installed correctly passport on a live server; using username and password, i get a token from server; when send this token to access to api it returns unauthenticated as message;
locally it works fine as expected. I want to know there the issue comes from.

Comment: Have you checked `oauth_access_tokens` table?

Comment: Yes, I have checked.

Comment: Have you checked that the `storage/oauth-private.key` and `storage/oauth-public.key` have been created on the live server correctly? If these are different to the local version, the same access_token won't work for both environments.

Comment: Yes, I have created both of flles, using command: php artisan passport:install --force

I don't know why it does' not work; any way to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is in live server you are use load balancer with two server (Multiple instance)?

if yes, then you have run `php artisan passport:keys` or `php artisan install` on each server, you will have generated different keys for each server. This means an access token issued on one instance might not be accepted on another.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand.

Using php function { getallheaders() } I have found that server drop away Authorization header.

Thanks.